# Django South is not creating a table for user_profiles

Tags: python, django, django-south

I wanted to reset my Django project's database, so I did the following steps:

1. Deleted my SQLite database
2. Did `python manage.py syncdb`
3. Did `python manage.py migrate users --fake`

After I create a new account and login, I get the following error message:

```
no such table: users_userprofile
```

Here is what my users model.py looks like:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User)
  joined_goals = models.ManyToManyField(Goal, related_name="joined_goals")
  followingGoals = models.ManyToManyField(Goal, related_name="following_goals")

  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.user.username

  def get_goals(self):
    try:
      goals = Goal.objects.filter(user=self.user)
      return goals
    except Goal.DoesNotExist:
      return []

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
      userProfile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

So, there is a UserProfile class, but South did not seem to make the table to hold the user profiles. When I do `python manage.py schemamigration users --auto`, it says that nothing has seemed to changed. How do I get it to create the userprofiles table?

Comment: Why did you use ``--fake``? That doesn't actually do the migration...

Comment: Side note: Your get_goals function will never raise the DoesNotExist exception.  If there are no matching goals you'll just get an empty queryset.

Comment: Did you run `./manage.py convert_to_south users`? You might need to do that before trying to generate a schemamigration

Comment: When I do convert_to_south users, I get this error: This application is already managed by South.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had this exact same problem. Turns out that there is a circular dependency of sorts when using South. To get around this problem, don't create a superuser when you run syncdb, but instead run:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

after you have created the database with syncdb. At this point, your profile table will have been created, and the post_save signal will succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to migrate the table without --fake option. Fake is usefull if you have changes applied in database but there are not in south_migrationhistory table.

Comment: I get this when I try to migrate users: Running migrations for users:
- Nothing to migrate.
 - Loading initial data for users.
No fixtures found.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work for some people:

```
python manage.py schemamigration myapp --initial
python manage.py migrate myapp
```